# Emulator not opening in Android

Tags: android, android-emulator

When I am running my app on emulator it dont open and gives the following Error.

```
[2011-01-08 16:16:56 - AudApp] ------------------------------
[2011-01-08 16:16:56 - AudApp] Android Launch!
[2011-01-08 16:16:56 - AudApp] adb is running normally.
[2011-01-08 16:16:56 - AudApp] Performing com.a1technology.AppingActivity activity launch
[2011-01-08 16:17:00 - AudApp] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'avd_2.3'
[2011-01-08 16:17:00 - Emulator] emulator: ERROR: the user data image is used by another emulator. aborting
```

Comment: are you sure that you're not already running an instance of the emulator? I get this error if i try to run a second emulator with the same image file. Maybe you haven't finsihed an earlier emulator not corerctly. YOu could show in the TaskManager if there is an emulator process already running.

Comment: I have checked TaskManger there is no emulator process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In : yourusername.android\avd\youremulatorname\

the folders:

**cache.img.lock**,  **sdcard.img.lock** and  **userdata-qemu.img.lock**

are created when the emulator starts and should be deleted when it closes. If the exit wasn't clean for some reason, then they aren't deleted. Delete them manually and it should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by restarting Eclipse with no emulator running.